# JQuery - Test for a css class element exists. .length doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I need to check for an element with a css class being in existance on my HTML.  I've Googled and searched here, and the common answer is to use .length > 0.

But that doesn't work.  I'm getting an "Object expected" error.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ($(".deleteLink").length != 0) 
  {
    $(".deleteLink").click(function () { return confirm('some message?'); });
  }
</script>
```

.deleteLink is a css class that belongs to a  tag that may or may not be present.  I'm getting the error on the conditional part.

Am I missing somethign??  Because it seems that everyone says to use .length...

Comment: Are you running that script before jQuery is loaded, or are you loading another JS framework like Prototype that might be stealing the `$` variable?

Comment: I agree with Ryan. "Object excpected" is generally a sign of JQuery not loaded or loaded incorrectly. Do you have a reference to JQuery in inside your HEAD tag?

Comment: Wow, thanks Ryan and others...I feel really dumb right now.  The Javascript in question was on a UserControl that being loaded into two different pages, the 2nd one of which did NOT have the JQuery loaded.  Thanks so much for the help, and I apologize for wasting everyone's time.  I quite a new with script, and I'm afraid it shows.  WIsh I could give 'answers' to everyone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking `length` is the correct way. There's something else wrong with your code. Did you perhaps forget to include jQuery? Is something clobbering `$`? Run it in something better than IE to get a more meaningful error message.

Also, a few tips. `if ($(...).length)` is enough because 0 is falsy, no need for the comparison. Also, you don't need to check if elements exist before manipulating them with jQuery (if it's something lightweight such as just attaching an event handler). Manipulating an empty jQuery result doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer since it wasn't probably the best and gave my vote to this one.

Comment: Thank for this.  I had in fact forgotten to include JQuery as it was a resusable control loaded on two different pages, one which had it and the other that didn't.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

### Why this code is ok?

Your script should not throw an error if jQuery is loaded and `$` is an alias for it (which is the default).

Also you can simply write:

```
$(".deleteLink").click(function(){ return confirm('some message?'); });
```

because the event handler will not be assigned to any element, if the selector does not find any.

### Possible problems & solutions

The problem you are facing is one of the following:

- the jQuery is not loaded, or
- `$` is not alias of `jQuery`.

To solve the first, just load jQuery before this part of the code. To solve the second you can simply use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

### How to improve the code

One additional possibility is that the element is not available when the code is being executed. If you do not load it dynamically, you can just execute the code when the DOM is ready:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".deleteLink").click(function(){ return confirm('some message?'); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a summation of the answers you already received.

The tags in your header should look something like this:

```
<head>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $(".deleteLink").click(function () { return confirm('some message?'); });
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

- load the jquery library before you use it
- $(function() {}); just guarantees that the script is only ran when your document is ready (the elements are loaded
- there is no need for that 'if' statement, if no elements are found, the click event will just attach to no elements.